# Configuration of max-len in eslint

Tags: eslintrc

I am trying to configure eslint and have this rule:

```
"max-len": [1, { "code": 120 }],
```

I know it's reading this file, because lint complains if I misconfigure this line.

Notice that this should warn at a length of 120. However when I lint my files I get this:

```
  5:1  error  This line has a length of 174. Maximum allowed is 140  max-len
```

I have know idea where the 140 is coming from. The docs say max-len has a default of 80. Also why the error? It seems like lint is disabling my max-len and adding some other random config.
What is going on?